# Issues with Get-WinEvent running in remoting session

Tags: powershell, remoting

Looks like below code does not work

```
$EventLogonIDs="4611","4624","4625","4634","4647","4648","4672","4774","4775","4    908","4964"
$MultipleIDLogEntries={Get-WinEvent -FilterHashtable     @{Logname='security';Id=@($using:EventLogonIDs)}}
Get-PSSession | % {icm -Session $_ -Command $MultipleIDLogEntries}
```

it returns below for each server

No events were found that match the specified selection criteria.
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (:) [Get-WinEvent], Exception
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NoMatchingEventsFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetWinEventCommand
    + PSComputerName        : testitservice.cloudapp.net

But if  $EventLogonIDs="4624", it just works with no issues.

What is wrong?
Thanks!

Comment: Why do you have spaces between 4 and 908?

Comment: No, this is because of indentation here. I did not get right away how to indent code block correctly

Comment: On the other hand it works this way

$MultipleIDLogEntries={$using:EventLogonIDs | % {Get-WinEvent -FilterHashtable @{Logname='security';Id=$_}}}
Get-PSSession | % {icm -Session $_ -Command $MultipleIDLogEntries}

Comment: nope it does not, it getting stuck

Comment: @AndreyVernigora I've seen this before, where FilterHashtable.Id only takes up to 23 numerical arguments, any more and it immediately returns with no "NoMatchingEventsFound" error. If you cut down the list to, say, 10 event id's, does it work?